# Image Upload doesn't work in Server. Works fine in localhost

Tags: ajax, razor, webmatrix

So, this code works just fine in localhost. It deletes the previous image and uploads the new one. It does nothing on server however. Any clue?

I have used AJAX for asynchorous call By the way if that makes a difference.

```
  var db=Database.Open("StarterSite");
  var contentQuery="Select * from Contents where id =@0";
  var content=db.QuerySingle(contentQuery,"1");
  var message="";
  var imgCount=0;
  var alreadyExist=false;

    try{
      if (IsPost && Request.Files.Count > 0) {
            bool deleteSuccess = false;
            var fileName = "";
            var photoName = "";
            var fileSavePath = "";
            var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
            var toDelete=Request["toDelete"];
            var toUpload=Request["toUpload"];

            if(uploadedFile.ContentLength>0){
                 @******************DELETE***************@
                    var fullPath = Server.MapPath("~/img/" + toDelete);
                    if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                        {
                                File.Delete(fullPath);
                                deleteSuccess = true;
                        }
            @****************UPLOAD*******************@
                  fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
                    fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/img/" +
                      fileName);
                    uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
                    var updateQuery="Update Contents Set "+toUpload +"=@0";
                    db.Execute(updateQuery, fileName);
                    //Response.Redirect("editMode.cshtml");
          }
       }
    }
    catch(HttpException ex){
      message="Image size you selected was too large. Please select a different Image.";
    }
```

Comment: `var fullPath = Server.MapPath("~/img/" + toDelete);` Try using a relative path instead.

Comment: can you tell me a little more?

Comment: Go to your server and into the `img` directory, hit `pwd` there and replace the the `~/img` in your code with the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the permission of the folder to 777.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that please?

Comment: In your filezilla, access your server and right click on the folder and change the permission. Try 755 or 777. http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/wordpress/navigation-customization/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-filezilla-on-your-ftp-site/

Comment: But I am not using filezilla. I am using web deploy in webmatrix.

Comment: I see. How did you upload the files in your server? Where can you view your folders from the server?

Comment: I am very new to this. I don't know how to access files from the server. I just know how to upload. May be the host I have don't have that service since I only pay like 5 bucks?

Comment: Try to check if the host have support and ask how to change permissions, commonly your problem occurs in server because of folder permissions. Do you get errors during uploading in server? If not, then must be really permissions.

Comment: Thanks :) I will do that

Comment: Welcome, hope it helps :)