# Flask Upload Image works only on Localhost, not in Online Server

Tags: python, flask

Good day all. I have a little issue on uploading image using flask. I can upload image on flask in localhost (the web app is hosted on my desktop). But when I loaded the flask app on Online Server, I always encounter the "FileNotFoundError". I also change the permission to 777 but still not working.

Here is the html upload code.

```
<form name="edit_vehicle_info" action="/vehicle_info_form/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formfield">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="changeVehicleImg">Vehicle Image</label>
    <input type="file" id="changeVehicleImg" name="changeVehicleImg" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

Here is the python upload code.

```
#vehicle_info_form
@app.route('/vehicle_info_form/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def vehicle_info_form():
    try:
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render_template(
                'vehicleInfo.html'
            )

        elif request.method == "POST":
            inputVehicleImg = request.files['changeVehicleImg']
            if inputVehicleImg.filename == "":
                inputVehicleImg_filename = ""
            else:
                print(inputVehicleImg.filename)
                print(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE'])
                inputVehicleImg_filename = secure_filename(inputVehicleImg.filename)
                inputVehicleImg.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE'], inputVehicleImg_filename))
            print ('success')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return redirect(url_for('vehicle_info_form'))
```

The python upload code can print the `inputVehicleImg.filename` and `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE']` then after that, the error occurs.

Here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1632, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1858, in process_response
    self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 924, in save_session
    return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 363, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 166, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous/url_safe.py", line 42, in dump_payload
    json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 133, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj, **self.serializer_kwargs))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 85, in dumps
    return json.dumps(_tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 167, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Projects/FMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 81, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'FileNotFoundError' is not JSON serializable
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: 1. You don't set permissions to 777! Never! 2. Your error is related to session handling but there is no session used in the code, also the code you showed is not referenced in the traceback. I assume the error is caused by something you did not show us.

Comment: Hi @KlausD.Thanks for the advice for not setting permission to 777. 1.) I just try it according to this post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591899/image-upload-doesnt-work-in-server-works-fine-in-localhost`. 2.) I just show the code where I have some issues which is the upload of image. Thank you for your input on this.

Comment: @hibrit-usta I reverted you edit since the stack trace is hardly readable if formatted as a quote. Keep it as code-formatted!

Comment: @KlausD. Okey.I leave it as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by updating the `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE']`. 
I use `os.getcwd()` to get the full current path and add the path where the image should be save.

First I check what is the root of the error by adding `try` and `except FileNotFoundError:`.

```
#vehicle_info_form
@app.route('/vehicle_info_form/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def vehicle_info_form():
    try:
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render_template(
                'vehicleInfo.html'
            )

        elif request.method == "POST":
            inputVehicleImg = request.files['changeVehicleImg']
            if inputVehicleImg.filename == "":
                inputVehicleImg_filename = ""
            else:
                print(inputVehicleImg.filename)
                print(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE'])
                inputVehicleImg_filename = secure_filename(inputVehicleImg.filename)
                try:
                    inputVehicleImg.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE'], inputVehicleImg_filename))
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    print("File does not exist")
            print ('success')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return redirect(url_for('vehicle_info_form'))
```

I try to upload an image and return in the console `File does not exist`.

Then I check the path of `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE']` where the image should be uploaded.

```
print(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE'])
```

And there I found out that the path is not the same in my online server so I update it.

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
print(path) 

UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE = path + "/apps/FMS/static/images/vehicleInfo"

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER_IMG_VEHICLE
```